# JGroups version change

Tags: java, cluster-computing, jgroups

Going to upgrade the current Jgroup version from 4.1.3 to 4.2.*. Looking for comparative analysis between the two versions such as features, bug-fixes, any best practices. Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete SCM changelog between that release and the latest `4.2.20.Final` release:

https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/compare/JGroups-4.1.3.Final...jgroups-4.2.20.Final

You can also head over to `Releases` section in the Jira and see changes for each release:

https://issues.redhat.com/projects/JGRP?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:release-page&status=released

Another option is to filter issues in Jira resolved between those two versions.